# Getting the main NetworkAdaptor MacAddress in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I'm trying to get the main adaptors' physical address.

first I get the LocaIpAddress of the machine in the following script:

```
    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }

    throw new System.Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}
```

What I try to do next is to compare this local ip with all the network adaptors' ip to find out which one is the main adaptor and then get its physical address.
In the folloing script:

```
PhysicalAddress physicalAddress;
void GetNetworkInterfacesWin()
{
    GetExternalIp();
    IPGlobalProperties computerProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();


    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection ipList = adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
        foreach(UnicastIPAddressInformation uipai in ipList)
        {
            if(uipai.Address.ToString() == GetLocalIPAddress())
            {
                physicalAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();
                print(physicalAddress);
                print(uipai.Address.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }

        byte[] bytes = physicalAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        string mac = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {

            mac = string.Concat(mac + (string.Format("{0}", bytes[i].ToString("X2"))));
            if (i != bytes.Length - 1)
            {
                mac = string.Concat(mac + "-");
            }
        }
        info += mac + "\n";

        info += "\n";
    } 
    debugtext.text = info;
    Debug.Log(info);
}
```

the problem is that the`physicalAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();` value returns an empty string, hence, `debugtext.text = info;    Debug.Log(info);` at the end is " ".

If there are other workarounds to ignore virtual adaptors and get the connected and active adaptor's physical address, I'd really appreciate you sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier method woking on windows, so for anyone wondering:

```
void GetNetworkInterfaces()
    {
        string physicalAddress = "";

        NetworkInterface[] nice = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface adaper in nice)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adaper.GetIPProperties();

            if (properties.DnsSuffix.Contains("lan"))
            {
                physicalAddress = adaper.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                macAddress = physicalAddress;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

apparently physical adaptors have the suffix `lan`. you can use it to check if it's physical or not.

Comment: It's not necessary that physical adaptors have ``lan`` suffix. So ``properties.DnsSuffix`` may be always empty. Don't rely on that.